# Free SSL setup on Heroku for a react-app using LetsEncrypt

Tags: ssl, nginx, heroku, ssl-certificate, heroku-api

To start with I really don't want to pay for hobby dyno on heroku. I am well aware of their ACM process. I am trying to be a little careful with spends as I am testing something.

My current setup is as follows:

Namecheap (domain xyz.com) -> xyz.herokuapp.com (with DNS Name configured correctly)

This is configured correctly and works great for HTTP. I have a task at hand to obtain certifactes from LetsEncrypt (because they are free), and integrated it to app deployed on `heroku`.

The app is a simple react-app, built using `create-react-app`. I have followed the steps to obtain a certificate from LetsEncrypt, and the certbot is asking me to place the certificate in this path `public/.well-known/acme-challenge/<cert-string>`. The content of the file in that path contains the .

The problem I am having is, the route `localhost:3000/.well-known/acme-challenge/<cert-string>` works well in my dev environment. When I deployed the react app to heroku, the route `/.well-known/acme-challenge/<cert-string>` is heading to a `304` and I am unable to facilitate the certbot to complete the validation step.

After a few hours of debugging I understood the architecture inside heroku better, and I have understood that this is a heroku buildpack related problem. My current understanding of the issue is as follows:

- heroku blocks access to `/.well-known/acme-challenge/<cert-string>`
- and I have to find a way to unblock this ^ .. so that `certbot` can validate my cert process.

I did some research and understood that there is a way to by-pass the nginx.conf. Is this really possible?

Looking for some guidance here.

---

Edit1

I have tried some approaches here https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/issues/218 - they did not work well.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Facing the same issue.

Comment: @zero_cool this is simply not possible in heroku. Their business model depends on this, the SSL enablement route is controlled by them for dynos. The last I checked they dont allow for this.